# repeat a video in WMP in c++

Tags: c++, wmp, wmplib

I want a video to be repeated infinite number of times till i press enter key or anyother key stroke.
The event part can be handled easily. What im worried about is how to repeat or loop the video continuously.
A little research showed me that the IWMPSettings has a SetMode function which can be used in following manner to loop video
SetMode("loop",true); But however, this doesnt work as i think this function works only if u have playlist.

Is there no alternative to run a single video continuously without using PlayList? If not, how do i create playlist?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say whether this is viable since the constraints of your problem aren't known, but it may be easier just input the corresponding keyboard shortcuts for whatever you want to do in wmp.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/media-player-keyboard-shortcuts